# How to better manage redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a expenses splitter app where the user can create a trip sheet, add expenses that everyone did on a trip. It then calculates who owes whom. I am planning to use Redux to manage state. Need feedback on the redux store design that I came up with. Attaching the screenshot of the state

```
const demoState = {
    trips:[{
        tripName: "Trip to New York",
        travellers:["Will", "Mike", "Lucas", "Dustin"],
        expenses:[{
            expnese:"Flights",
            whoPaid: "Mike",
            forWhom:["Will", "Mike", "Lucas", "Dustin"],
            howMuch:150
        },
        {
            expnese:"Hotels",
            whoPaid: "Lucas",
            forWhom:["Will", "Mike", "Lucas", "Dustin"],
            howMuch: 120
        }   
        ]
    },
    {
        tripName: "Trip to StarCourt mall",
        travellers:["Will", "Mike", "Lucas", "Dustin", "Eleven", "Max"],
        expenses:[{
            expnese:"Movies",
            whoPaid: "Max",
            forWhom:["Will", "Mike", "Lucas", "Dustin", "Eleven", "Max"],
            howMuch: 30
        },
        {
            expnese:"Popcorn",
            whoPaid: "Dustin",
            forWhom:["Lucas", "Dustin", "Eleven", "Max"],
            howMuch: 5
        }
        ]
    }

]
}
```

Comment: Hi rahul, see my solution below, I think it will be helpful to you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, seems like a pretty good structure for your store. You likely could centralize all of this data into a single-reducer like `tripsReducer`.

For the `travelers`, `forWhom` and `whoPaid` fields, I would recommend using an array of objects `[{...}]` instead of an array of strings `[""]`. In the likely event that a trip will have multiple people with the same name, you would want each user to have a unique identifier. You then have a way to differentiate between the users.

That will make it simpler to perform actions like calculating who paid/getting the total cost of each person and etc.

```
const demoState = {
    trips:[{
        tripName: "Trip to New York",
        travellers:[{id: 1, name: "Will"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}, {id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}],
        expenses:[{
            expnese:"Flights",
            whoPaid: {id: 2, name: "Mike"},
            forWhom: [{id: 1, name: "Will"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}, {id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}],
            howMuch:150
        },
        {
            expnese:"Hotels",
            whoPaid: {id: 3, name: "Lucas"},
            forWhom:[{id: 1, name: "Will"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}, {id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}],
            howMuch: 120
        }   
        ]
    },
    {
        tripName: "Trip to StarCourt mall",
        travellers:[{id: 1, name: "Will"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}, {id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}, {id: 5, name: "Eleven"}, {id: 6, name: "Eleven"}, {id: 7, name: "Max"}],
        expenses:[{
            expnese:"Movies",
            whoPaid: [{id: 7, name: "Max"}],
            forWhom:[{id: 1, name: "Will"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}, {id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}, {id: 5, name: "Eleven"}, {id: 6, name: "Eleven"}, {id: 7, name: "Max"}],
            howMuch: 30
        },
        {
            expnese:"Popcorn",
            whoPaid: [{id: 4, name: "Dustin"}],
            forWhom:[{id: 3, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 4, name: "Dustin"}, {id: 6, name: "Eleven"}, {id: 7, name: "Max"}],
            howMuch: 5
        }
        ]
    }

]
}
```

Also, how was this season of Stranger Things?

Comment: First things first: season 3 was mindblowing. Loved it!!
I did not take into account the fact that 2 travelers could have the same name so yeah id would be a pretty good way to differentiate the two.
Thanks @christopher Ngo :)

Comment: @Rahulnayak Awesome! I'll have to catch-up on that after rewatching Game of Thrones. As for your redux-store structure, I think after changing the array of strings to be array of objects, you should be good to go. Ultimately, it will expand depending on what other features you might want to add, but for your app's intended purpose I think this is fine. If you have any other questions, please let me know. Otherwise, please do consider upvoting and marking my answer as the solution :)

Comment: thanks. Making an array of objects does make much more sense. Thank you! My current reputation does not allow me to upvote or mark it as a solution but you have my vote :)